# Windows path searching in LoadLibrary with manifest

Tags: windows, dll, manifest, loadlibrary, side-by-side

If you call `LoadLibrary` without a path (e.g., `LoadLibrary("whatever.dll")`, Windows will generally follow its standard search algorithm, the same one it uses to find EXEs.

My question is this: suppose that an application manifest specifies specifies a particular version of a system DLL, say, comctl32.dll 6.0. In that case, will `LoadLibrary("comctl32.dll")` go immediately to the correct side-by-side folder, or does it still perform some kind of search?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [Microsoft:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682586.aspx)

> Applications can control the location from which a DLL is loaded by specifying a full path, using DLL redirection, or by using a manifest. If none of these methods are used, the system searches for the DLL at load time as described in this topic.

So yes, if a manifest is present, it will directly go to the SxS folder.

Answer (score 0):

To probe the loader when having troubles with missing libraries, you can use the "sxstrace" feature. [www.codeproject.com/KB/DLL/QueryAssemblyIdentities.aspx](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/DLL/QueryAssemblyIdentities.aspx) gives some details about the dependencies between manifest and WinSxs.