# Where does DLLImport look for unmanaged DLLs?

Tags: .net, unmanaged, dllimport

A quick question: When declaring the DLLImport Attribute in .Net, where does the runtime look to resolve that DLL dependency? Would I have to dump the DLL and all of *its* dependencies in the bin folder?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think it is working like LoadLibrary.

Maybe [Windows path searching in LoadLibrary with manifest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154281/windows-path-searching-in-loadlibrary-with-manifest) will be helpfull.

**Edit** [Dynamic-Link Library Search Order](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682586(VS.85).aspx) is probably what you want.

Comment: Let's suppose, that I have an application with Plugins subfolder. In Plugins, I've got an assembly, which uses DllImport to import native function from a DLL, which is also in this folder. Will Windows look inside this directory, or will it look only in application's root folder?

Comment: Does it depend on the target platform of the project? I ask because I'm using `DriverPackagePreinstall()` from `DIFxAPI.dll` - if I compile to x86 or "Any CPU", it doesn't work on a 64-bit machine, but if I compile to x64 it does. According to the docs, a 64-bit version of the dll is required so I can only conclude that it's using a different dll when building with x64 as opposed to x86

Answer (score 2):

Generally, you'd expect it to look at whatever's defined in the user's Path.

To find out what this contains, from a command prompt, type `echo %PATH%` [Enter]